# Android App Shortcuts doesn't work

Tags: android, xml

I updated Android Studio to support API 25 and implement it in project. I also look for different resources to find right answer on my question, but with no luck. First, I need to say that I test app on Android 6.0.1 with Action and Nova Launcher (but Google apps working).
So, I implemented in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

Created `shortcuts.xml` in `xml` - `res`. There, I enter this:

```
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="sc1"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_kalendar"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_kalendar"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_kalendar_long"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/message_off">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        android:targetClass="com.ips.orto.MainActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.ips.orto" />
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.ips.orto"
        android:targetClass="com.ips.orto.kalendar.Kalendar"/>
</shortcut>

<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="sc2"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_else"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_else"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_else_long"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/message_off">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        android:targetClass="com.ips.orto.MainActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.ips.orto" />
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.ips.orto"
        android:targetClass="com.ips.orto.else.Something"/>
</shortcut>
```

I try removing `android:` in attributes, still not working. Also, I add `android:exported="true"` to `Activity` which are point to in `Shortcuts` and I didn't create `shortcuts.xml` in any special v- bucket.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend that you test on Android 7.1, such as using the emulator. I have not tried Nova Launcher (IIRC, their app shortcut support is in beta), but Action Launcher is definitely broken at the present time. Manifest app shortcuts that work on the Pixel and on the 7.1 emulator do not work on Action Launcher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I finally find the answer. Catch is very simple. Code:

```
<activity ...>
<meta-data 
    android:name="android.app.shortcuts"     
    android:resource="@xml/shortcuts"/></activity>
```

Means to add `meta` not only in `application` part of `Mainfest`, but also in `Activity` for which you create definition in `shortcuts.xml` (for example, if you define shortcut to `ThirdActivity`, you will add above code to that `Activity` in `Manifest`). Also, just chosen activities need this line:

```
android:exported="true"
```

and after that it works as supposed to both in Action and Nova Launcher, as well as in Android 7.1 emulator.

Comment: this really helped me, perfect solution.

Comment: Althought this solution worked in your case. it is important to take in account that `<meta-data ... />` must be inside the activity whose `intent-filters` are set to `android.intent.action.MAIN` action and the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` category as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts)

Comment: Looks like it's no longer necessary to declare as child of <application> element (tested on version 7.0.57).

Answer (score 0):

shortcuts.xml file must be here, **res/xml-v25/shortcuts.xml** http://sunilkmrnishad.blogspot.in/2017/03/app-shortcuts-android-nougat-71-feature.html

Comment: Obsolete link.!